# PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tendo problemas em efetuar uma consulta no banco de dados. Já tentei o mesmo comando no banco e funcionou normalmente. Segue o código:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY nome;");          
$linha = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$linha['matricula']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linha['nome']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$linha['nivel_acesso']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Faltou passar a conexão para o `mysqli_query()` que é o primeiro argumento.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!